# Insert NULL into SQL when string is empty

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

trying to insert NULL when there wasn't selected anything in my combobox but when I do this:

```
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@odjezd", cb_odjezd.Text == string.Empty ?
                                               null : cb_odjezd.Text);
```

I receive following exception:

> The parameterized query expects the parameter @ odjezd

May someone help me solve this please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use [DbNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx) value instead.

So it becomes

```
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@odjezd", 
         string.IsNullOrEmpty(cb_odjezd.Text) ? DbNull.Value : cb_odjezd.Text);
```

**EDIT**

Acroding to *acepted*  answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503266/type-of-conditional-expression-cannot-be-determined-because-there-is-no-implicit), it should be enough in your case to `(object)DBNull.Value`

The issue is that C# expects the *same type* values in condition here, but in one case you 
set `DbNull.Value` in another `string`. So casting `DbNull.Value` to object make "pass" that rule.

Comment: It says: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between Systém.DBnull and string. Any ideas?

Comment: Insert a cast of one side or the other to `(object)` to make it compile, e.g. `? (object)DbNull.Value : cb_objezd.Text`

Comment: @Marek One thing ,Your `datatype` is `nullable` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use DBNull

```
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@odjezd", cb_odjezd.Text == string.Empty ? DBNull.value : cb_odjezd.Text);
```

try using this :

```
if (cb_odjezd.Text== string.Empty)
{
    prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@odjezd", DBNull.Value);
}
else
{
    prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@odjezd", cb_odjezd.Text);
}
```

The keyword null represents an invalid reference. The class System.DbNull represents a nonexistent value in a database field.

Comment: *Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '`System.DBNull`' and '`string`'*

Comment: It says: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between Systém.DBnull and string may you please help me solve this out please?

Comment: @Marek The error tells you that both side of `?`(Operator ,branches etc.) have different types , You have to implicitly convert them to a common type .

Answer (score 2):

Either the type of `first_expression` and `second_expression` must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.-[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

`?:` can not cast `type` itself ,Here you are returning either a `string` or `DbNull` type value ,So you have to cast instance of `_objezd.Text`to object type to make it compatible .

```
 prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@odjezd", 
  _odjezd.Text == string.Empty ? DbNull.Value : (object)cb_odjezd.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

DBNull is [frankly a bit of a PITA - and it bites lots of people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488727/what-is-the-point-of-dbnull/9632050#9632050). However, one way to avoid this pain is to use an ORM or micro-ORM that will *make this problem go away*. For example, with [dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper):

```
int id = ...
string odjezd = ...
...
connection.Execte("insert SomeTable (...) values (@id, @odjezd, ...)",
     new {id, odjezd, ... });
```

Here dapper will automatically parameterize the values correctly, inlcuding treating `null`-references and empty `Nullable<T>` as `DBNull.Value`. Plus it means you avoid all the "fun" of ADO.NET, simply having to worry about:

- connection management
- the sql
- what the parameter values are (but not the parameterization itself)

Note that dapper also has great tools in terms of *materialization* too, to avoid all the pain of data-readers.

Answer (score 1):

Try my replied solution from this post
[my reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62129998/13657621)

> Actually it is a type confusion problem which should be an compiler
>   time problem.  But cause in runtime when nullable string is passed to
>   `AddWithValue(string, object)`.
>
> If you want `string`, cast `DBNull.Value` to `string` by microsoft c# 
>   DBNull library build-in method `DBNull.Value.ToString()` equivalently
>   `string.Empty`.
>
> If you want a generic type cast the string (object)str.